# .Net Core 3.1 Web API CORS Policy block after adding UseAuthentication() in Startup.cs

Tags: azure, authentication, cors, asp.net-core-webapi

I created an ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API and a Javascript client that calls the Web API methods to get data.

The Web API is secured by an Azure AD app registration to prevent the usage of the API by foreign users or clients. The Web API is currently running on an internal network.

The problem at the moment is that I need to enable CORS in my API. I already got CORS enabled on my API and the Javascript client could get responses from the API but since I added the Azure Authentication with the `app.UseAuthentication()` method I get CORS errors again

I added following to my `Startup.cs` `ConfigureServices` and `Configure` methods to enable CORS:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();

    services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(Configuration);

    services.AddCors(o =>
        {
            o.AddPolicy("Allow", builder =>
                builder.WithOrigins("https://www.example.com")
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader());
        });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseCors("Allow");

    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
}
```

The `services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(COnfiguration)` and `app.UseAuthentication()` are used to enable the authentication with my Azure AD. The properties for this authentication are set in the `appsettings.json`. This authentication is also already working.

But since I added this authentication with the two mentioned methods, I get CORS policy errors when using the API.

Before I added this two methods everything is working and I don't get CORS errors. While I tested everything I recognized that when I remove the `app.UseAuthentication()` call from the `Configure` method, I don't get the CORS errors and my requests coming from my Javascript client has the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

When I add `app.UseAuthentication()`, the header isn't present in my request.

This is the error I currently get:

> Access to fetch at 'https://example_XXX.com/api/example/example' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I already tried to add the `[EnableCors("Allow")]` tag to my controller, but this also did not work.

Maybe anyone of you has an idea what the problem is and why I'm getting this error when I'm adding the `app.UseAuthentication()` method?

If you think you need any more information about the problem feel free to comment and i will provide. I changed my URLs to examples.

### UPDATE:

I recognized that the CORS error only occur when deploying the api and hosting it over IIS. Maybe anyone is familiar with that.

Comment: Try swapping the calls to `services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication` and `services.AddCors`. See https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/2702#issuecomment-743889685

Comment: Cross check once the CORS policy origin which you have enabled is same as the origin of the incoming request.

Comment: The origin is correct. As I said I don't get the CORS error when I remove the app.UseAuthentication() method from the Configure() method. Withouth app.UseAuthentication() the CORS error does not show and the request I send also gets the Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header. When I add app.UseAuthentication() this header isn't present on my request.